# PHP htaccess redirect page not found

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have one website in which I am fetching the the data using htaccess rule the URL but it always redirect to page not found. If I use the direct URL instead of htaccess url then it works fine.

Nice url: http://apis.jaspee.com/services/getCMS?pageid=2

Real url: http://apis.jaspee.com/services/srvcRest.php?rqst=getCMS&pageid=2

`.htaccess` code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ srvcRest.php?rqst=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ srvcRest.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ srvcRest.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>

<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
    Allow from all
</Limit>
```

Can anyone say what's wrong I am doing?

Comment: In the nice url you got a param named `id` but the second url expects a param named `pageid`. So instead of `http://apis.jaspee.com/services/srvcRest.php?rqst=getCMS&pageid=2` you're getting `http://apis.jaspee.com/services/srvcRest.php?rqst=getCMS&id=2`

Comment: sorry it's my mistake..both have the pageid..

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `services/` to be sent to your `rqst` parameter:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^services/(.*)$ services/srvcRest.php?rqst=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^services/(.*)$ services/srvcRest.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^services/(.*)$ services/srvcRest.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>

<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
    Allow from all
</Limit>
```